# Show, by an example, that $h$ need not be continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a topological space with $X=E \cup F$ Let $f: E \to Y$ and $g:F \to Y$ with $f=g$ on $E \cap F$ be continuous respect to the relative toplogies. Note that $h=f \cup g$ is a function from X into Y.
Show, by an example, that $h$ need not be continuous.

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\{1,2\}$ with indiscrete topology, $Y=\{1,2\}$ with discrete topology, $E=\{1\}$, $F=\{2\}$, $f(1)=1$, $g(2)=2$.